# Filter var for calling a shellscript with system on php

Tags: php, shell, system, filter-var

i need to filter those var to call system in php and execute a shell script. What filter_var SANITIZE macro i need to use to remove ";" or problems during shell execution? Like unwanted chars..etc..etc

This is my code testing example, now i've hardcoded the var for testing.. Thanks!

```
$ragionesociale = $_GET["ragionesociale"]; /* Alphanumeric with spaces next trimmed*/
$api = $_GET["ragionesociale"]; /* Uri with space encoded*/
$sito = $_GET["sito"]; /* Uri with space encoded*/
$meta = $_GET["meta"]; /*Address, CF, a lot of things...*/
$tmp_dir = "tmp_app";


if(!filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "ragionesociale") ||
   !filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "sito") ||
   !filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "meta") ||
   !filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "api")
){  
 echo("Input type does not exist");
 exit();
}

 system("../configmyapp2.sh ".$ragionesociale." ".$api." ".$sito." ".$meta." ".$tmp_dir);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [escapeshellarg()](http://docs.php.net/escapeshellarg).

> escapeshellarg() adds single quotes around a string and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument. This function should be used to escape individual arguments to shell functions coming from user input. The shell functions include exec(), system() and the backtick operator.

Answer (score 1):

If this can be triggered by other users then I would not go by this method.

Its very dangerous, especially with your multiple parameters and sanitization rules.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Pass your command line parameters through this and you're safe ;) Also I'd recommend you use exec() instead of system() or even shell_exec() because you'll be able to get the return value from your script as well as any text output which you may want to use.

Comment: if i use escapeshellarg on my GET vars and i put a shell command like ;echo ciao. the shell will exec an echo! It's not enought, i need other check... any suggestions?

Comment: Then check out it's cousin: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php pass your entire command line string through this one ;) cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in sanitization filter that can do this; however, you can fake it with [`FILTER_CALLBACK`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php) and `escapeshellarg` like this:

```
$var = filter_var($input, FILTER_CALLBACK, array('options' => 'escapeshellarg'));
```